# Calender open Event

Tags: android, calendar

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    // Android 2.2+
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events/"
            + String.valueOf(eventId)));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

i am trying to open exactly Event with the Event ID return when add to Calendar , Problem That calendar start with white screen and then close return to app

Comment: And what is going wrong?

Comment: not opening event on calender :)

Comment: Any log or stack trace?

Comment: have u added Permissions?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" >
    </uses-permission>